# DJango ORM - analogue for LEFT JOIN query

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

models.py

```
class Products(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()
      price = models.IntegerField()

class Products_Images(models.Model):
      products  = models.ForeignKey(Products)
      image = models.ImageField()
      name = models.CharField()
```

I need to get PRODUCTS and only ONE or NO image for each product.

Like this:

```
SELECT Products.*,Products_Images.* FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Products_Images on Products.id=Products_Images.product_id AND Products_Images.name LIKE '%pizza%'
WHERE Products.price >= 50
```

Comment: Your SQL is invalid. What does `on Products=Products_Images.product_id` mean?

Comment: fixed
Products.id=Products_Images.product_id